Covariant Euler-Lagrange Computation - Mathematica
Does anybody know of a software (or software package) that can solve the Euler-Lagrange equations for a manifestly-covariant field Lagrangian density? Mathematica has a "Variational Methods" package, but none of the examples given are in manifestly-covariant form. I am not very experienced with any of the analytical computation softwares or their packages. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

You might want to be more specific. How do the Euler-Lagrange equations look like? Are they PDEs, for example?
